What are the consequences of not having the "Combining Game Effects" rule?
The following rule, found in the 2014 DMG (p. 252), is not included in the 2024 PHB or the 2024 DMG:

Combining Game Effects
Different game features can affect a target at the same time. But when
two or more game features have the same name, only the effects of one
of them—the most potent one—apply while the durations of the effects
overlap. For example, if a target is ignited by a fire elemental's
Fire Form trait, the ongoing fire damage doesn't increase if the
burning target is subjected to that trait again. Game features include
spells, class features, feats, racial traits, monster abilities, and
magic items. See the related rule in the "Combining Magical Effects"
section of chapter 10 in the Player's Handbook.

Assuming you're only using the new Core Rulebooks for your games, how is the game impacted without this rule?
Note that the rule "Combining Magical Effects" mentioned in that text is included in the 2024 PHB, with the name Combining Spell Effects.

Not much to say yet
A complete answer won't be possible until we have the new 2024 Monster Manual. Most potentially stackable things (generally class features) in the PHB include their own anti-stacking protections (e.g. a Paladin's Aura of Protection explicitly doesn't stack with an overlapping Aura of Protection from another Paladin). It's possible the Monster Manual does the same thing, or they may include a version of the Combining Game Effects rule in it to avoid lots of repetition.
If they don't do it, well, certain monsters are going to get a lot more powerful. But we won't know without the revised monsters to look at.
